# What's the difference between "a contract with" and "a contract from"?

Tags: difference, phrase-choice

What is the difference between "a contract with" and "a contract from"? For example, in the sentence

> SpaceX has a $1.6 billion contract from NASA.

Can I replace "from" by "with" in this sentence? Or does "from" indicate something like the contract is made by NASA and endorsed by SpaceX, and if "with" is used, this information will be lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speakers will often use words loosely. They will have in mind something which is related to the word they're using.

The contract no doubt involves supplying NASA with goods and/or services, and thus the contract is a kind of "order".  Vendors and suppliers receive such orders *from* customers.

> We just got a big order from GM to supply them with ball bearings.
>
> We just got a big contract from GM. <sup>loose, a little sloppy</sup>

So that sentence means merely that SpaceX has a $1.6 billion deal with NASA where NASA is the customer and SpaceX is the supplier.

Answer (score 0):

I think this specific sentence you have here means that spacex is built or developed upon a contract that NASA had with someone. If you use "contract with", then I think spacex should be one of the parties in the contract.